# Solving rank equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose we are given a (finite) matrix $A$ with entries $a_{ij} \in k[w_1, \ldots, w_n]$ which are polynomial expressions of $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ over some field $k$. For a fixed integer $m$, is there a way to determine all points $p=(w_1, \ldots, w_n) \in \mathbb A^n(k) = k^n$ such that
$$\operatorname{rank} A=m,$$ i.e. which $p\in k^n$ makes the rank of $A$ to be $m$?

Comment: You can calculate the invariant factors $d_i$ ($i=1,\dots, N$) without much bother, and then you need to solve $d_{m+1}(w_1,\dots, w_n)=0,d_{m}(w_1,\dots, w_n)\not=0$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician How do you calculate the SNF without letting $w_i$ take any values, i.e. leaving them as indetermine? We do not think of $A$ as a constant matrix but rather a function of $p$.

Comment: Sorry, I have misled myself. $k[x]$ yes, $k[x,y]$ no.

Comment: I might know a source, but can you give an explicit non-trivial example?  Say with n=3 or 4?

Comment: @rrogers I'm curious about the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
d_1 & 0 & d_2 & 0 \\
-d_2 s & 0 & d_1 & 0 \\
a_1 & b_1 & a_2 & b_2 \\
-a_2 s & -s b_2 & a_1 & b_1 \\
-a_2 d_2 & -d_2 b_{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & d_1 & 0 & d_2 \\
0 & -d_2 s & 0 & d_1\end{array}\right)$ and $m=2$.

Comment: Okay, let me get this straight.   1) Given (a_1 ... d_2) you want equations in s such that the rank is two ( s=1 seems to come close)?   Or constraints on  (a_1 ... d_2) so that for a given s the rank is 2?

Comment: I'm not sure but Resultants from that chapter in https://smile.amazon.com/Algebraic-Scientists-Engineers-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821815350  might be what you want.

Comment: @rrogers There are seven variables. I want to find all values which makes the matrix have rank 2.

Answer (score 3):

The rank of a matrix is the size of its largest non-vanishing minor, so you can express your condition by polynomial equations in the matrix entries.

Answer (score 0):

I have reservations about this, Maxima, solution; although it corresponds to some other approaches I tried
Rewriting the particular problem to satisfy my pattern-seeking.
Using Maxima
$ M=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
d_{1} & d_{2} & 0 & 0\\
-sd_{2} & d_{1} & 0 & 0\\
a_{1} & a_{2} & b_{1} & b_{2}\\
-sa_{2} & a_{1} & -sb_{2} & b_{1}\\
-a_{2}d_{2} & 0 & -d_{2}b_{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & d_{1} & d_{2}\\
0 & 0 & -sd_{2} & d_{1}
\end{array}\right]$
factor(triangularize(M));
$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
d_{1} & d_{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & d_{2}^{2}\cdot s+d_{1}^{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -b_{2}\cdot d_{2}\cdot(d_{2}^{2}\cdot s+d_{1}^{2})\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\left(b_{2}\right)^{2}\cdot d_{2}\cdot(d_{2}^{2}\cdot s+d_{1}^{2})\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$
The rank() command also gives these terms.

The only thing wrong with this is the $d_{2}$ in the top row. It should have been eliminated? I left it in because I might have missed something, but it seems wrong (a bug in Maxima?)
Analysis:

$(d_{2}^{2}\cdot s+d_{1}^{2}) =0 $ yields rank 1
$b_{2}=0$ yields rank 2
$d_{2}=0$ yields rank 2
$d_{1}=0$ yields rank 3

Comment: I prefer to use exterior/alternating products for this type of analysis.

That is because it automatically points down to the elementary definition of dependence/independence of linear conditions and fits any dimension/size. It starts out with vector, cross-product, triple product; but these are specialized and actually more complicated than the general alternating products.

But Maxima didn't have specialized routines for your type of problem and the standard function yielded too many terms to be useful. Sage didn't seem to have a function that didn't drag in extra concerns.

Do not use the “echelon” form because I think it will make incorrect decisions when you want to later set terms to zero or not; it normalizes.

Constructive comments welcome :)

Comment: I was surprised that no computer algebra system seems to have a good functions written for this: most of them relies on knowing which elements are zero and not, but one cannot know that in this problem.

Comment: I couldn't find one and haven't come up with a scheme that I am willing to implement.  To me, some foundational problems exist.  
1) The possibility of dividing by zero when one is operating on variables of unknown value during gaussian elimination.
2) A persistent CAS problem I have encountered: premature declaration of "zero".  That is dropping terms when a multiplication by zero is found; whereas one should wait to see if a division/denominator will cancel it out.   Late GCD tests or  L'Hopital's rule/algorithm might avoid this.   Of course, this means carrying around fractions for awhile

Comment: If you have this type of problem on an ongoing basis, I will write a routine implementing exterior/alternating products.  That should be foolproof but requires learning the fine points of some data representations (boring...).  Basically, you have to sort through a multitude of alternating products.  In this case, all two forms that are not zero and descendent three forms that are zero.  The alternating part isn't hard; phrasing the question for a Groebner analysis requires care; I think.

Comment: If you have any working algorithm that works for all matrices over an arbitrary field $k$, feel free to share (and it doesn't have to be code).